# Select and sum values in id laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, sum

I have a table that has user id values with innerjoin and points, I need to add these points.

```
$test = DB::table('users')
    ->orderBy('values.points', 'asc')
    ->join('values', 'values.id_user', '=', 'users.id_brother')
    ->get();
```

This displays:

```
user1 1
user1 1
user1 1
```

The value in Points needs to add up and display only once with the added points.

I need you to show:

```
User1 3
```

Comment: What database (and version) are you using?

Comment: Mysql 5.5 @rwd.

Comment: Are you just needing the user id and the sum from the query or are you using other attributes elsewhere as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `groupBy` id_brother and `sum` points. I am not %100 about your table structure and columns

```
return DB::table('users')
    ->orderBy('total', 'asc')
    ->join('values', 'values.id_user', '=', 'users.id_brother')
    ->groupBy('users.id_brother')
    ->get([
        'users.id_brother',
        DB::raw('sum(values.points) as total')
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use count method

look

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-count